# Pressing home button on Android - white screen when resuming app

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-activity

I'm creating an Android app using phonegap. Whenever I press the home button whilst I'm in my app and then try and open the app back up I get a white blank screen - which only disappears when the screen is touched.
Looking in logcat I get a message saying blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse after I touch the screen.

If I press the back button to get out of the app and then return - it works fine, so really unsure why it doesn't work for the home button.

This is my activity in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".PhoneGapActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.matt.android.theAppName.MESSAGE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

One thing that does work is to override the onpause method:

```
   @Override
     public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       this.finish();
   }
```

But this makes the activity restart - which is not ideal.

If anyone has any idea why this is I'd really appreciate any input, thanks.

EDIT:

The onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    int splashImageResourceIdentifier = getResources().getIdentifier("splash", "drawable", getPackageName());
    if (splashImageResourceIdentifier != 0) {
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", splashImageResourceIdentifier);
        super.loadUrl(WORK_DIR + getStartFileName(), 10000);
    } else {
        super.loadUrl(WORK_DIR + getStartFileName());
    }

    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
    this.appView.clearCache(false);
    this.appView.clearHistory();

    // Set some defaults
    this.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    this.appView.setHorizontalScrollbarOverlay(false);
    this.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    this.appView.setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(false);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra(Constants.EVENT.MESSAGE_RECEIVED)) {
        // Application is started by clicking on notification
        PushNotifications.handleMessage(getIntent());
    }

    // Set some defaults on the web view
    this.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    this.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    this.appView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    this.appView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(false);

    // Caching is preventin android 2.3.3 from working properly with REST calls (ETST-5834, ETST-6716)
    this.appView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    this.appView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

    /*
    Enabling hardware acceleration to make CSS rules like translate3d work properly.
    0x01000000 is actually WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED flag, but it doesn't exist in
    android 2.2.1 lib that is present in maven dependency management.
     */
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        getWindow().setFlags(0x01000000, 0x01000000);
    }
}
```

and I haven't got an onResume method in the activity.

Comment: can you post your onResume() method?

Comment: Post your onCreate() and onResume() method

Comment: I've added the oncreate method - and there isn't an onresume method  - thanks for replying.

Comment: add this line in onCreate method setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Yeah that killed the app - I think because its a phonegap app - with a webview inside of the android app - that's probably why

Comment: Which version of phonegap are you using? Looks like very old bugs from version 2.x

Comment: @matt by any chance did you find a fix for this?